# Exception Value: cannot import name TimeoutStateError when import Geocoder

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, import

I am trying to get coordinates from an address and uses pygeocoder to do it. But got this exception right after running the program. Can someone help check?

Traceback:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  103.                     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  319.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  347.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  342.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

File "/Users/Jack/fanju/src/wonew/grubcat/urls.py" in <module>
  10. from fanju.views import upload_app

File "/Users/Jack/fanju/src/wonew/grubcat/fanju/views.py" in <module>
  26. from fanju.views_restaurant import add_dummy_menu

File "/Users/Jack/fanju/src/wonew/grubcat/fanju/views_restaurant.py" in <module>
  11. from pygeocoder import Geocoder

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygeocoder.py" in <module>
  19. import requests

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py" in <module>
  58. from . import utils

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py" in <module>
  23. from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/compat.py" in <module>
  7. from .packages import charade as chardet

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py" in <module>
  3. from . import urllib3

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py" in <module>
  16. from .connectionpool import (

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py" in <module>
  12. from .util import resolve_cert_reqs, resolve_ssl_version, assert_fingerprint

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py" in <module>
  18. from .timeout import (

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/timeout.py" in <module>
  4. from ..exceptions import TimeoutStateError

Exception Type: ImportError at /

Exception Value: cannot import name TimeoutStateError
```

I made an attempt that I changed one line in `urllib3/util/timeout.py`. 
I changed the line `from ..exceptions import TimeoutStateError` to 
`from urllib3.exceptions import TimeoutStateError` and it works.

So what shall I do next? That lib should be a common lib I suppose

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have the same now and have no idea how to solve it. Installed python + python-requests on rhel6.5, run python and running `import requests` ends up with the same exception. On other machine with same installation it does not have any problems. I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, as I commented under original question, the problem was that I installed `urllib3` and `requests` libraries as rpm packages. Removing both of them and installing via `pip` led to Python installation in correct state and importing `requests` goes without exception.

Comment: I updated `requests` and the error didn't occur again.

Answer (score 0):

What is the code you are running?

But it seems as though you didnt write the exception's full name, it should be *ModuleName*.TimeoutStateError, from a quick google search and what you said it seems like it should be
urllib3.TimeoutStateError

Comment: Hi Tomer.z, I didn't paste any codes, as it's failed in import phase, the actual place where codes located hasn't been run yet. It's right after I click run in pycharm and homepage showing this exception. I looked into urllib3/util/timeout.py. There is this code: from socket import _GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
import time

from ..exceptions import TimeoutStateError

Comment: BTW, I tried to google TimeoutStateError or from ..exceptions import TimeoutStateError, no luck. Hardly find even one matching information.

Comment: **I made an attempt that I changed one line in urllib3/util/timeout.py 
I changed the line from ..exceptions import TimeoutStateError to 
from urllib3.exceptions import TimeoutStateError, it works. So what shall I do next? That lib should be a common lib I suppose**

Comment: what should you do next in regards to what?

Answer (score 0):

I use other way to do it. By using parsing the json format from google. Thanks.